# What constitutes a new major revision (the first number in the version) in the Linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel

Wikipedia says

> The jump from 2.6.x to 3.x wasn't because of a breaking update, but rather the first release of a new versioning scheme introduced as a more convenient system.

but it doesn't provide a reason for any other jump in major revision (like 4.x to 5.x). What are the reasons this occurs? What was the reason for the jump to 5.x?

Comment: These days? Linus getting bored of counting over 30 or 40, that's when the last couple of major versions started. https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2015/02/linux-version-dilemma-linus-torvalds-is-running-out-of-fingers-and-toes/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major numbers don’t mean anything, they are incremented when the “minor” version becomes too large.

For a good, recent overview of the meaning of kernel versions (and the false expectations they create), see [Rolling stable kernels](https://lwn.net/Articles/871989/) in LWN:

> To address that, the plan was made to move to 3.0 and to increase the second number (minor version) with each release, effectively dropping the use of the third element of the version number for mainline releases. Levin called this the "finger and toes" version-number scheme, because Torvalds said that he could count up to around 20 "minor" releases before running out of digits and needing to increase the major version number. So after 3.19, 4.0 was released.

4.20 was the limit for Linus, so it was followed by 5.0; see [the release announcement](https://lwn.net/Articles/781206/):

> But I'd
> like to point out (yet again) that we don't do feature-based releases,
> and that "5.0" doesn't mean anything more than that the 4.x numbers
> started getting big enough that I ran out of fingers and toes.

Comment: Hmm, well then it seems that the only reason Linus released 4.20 is so that he can have a version named 4.20.

Comment: Yes, that’s a reasonable interpretation. Nowadays kernel version numbers are really just time-based tags; they could be anything at all.